# Como retornar valores de uma Activity filha em Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Olá, estou começando a trabalhar com Kotlin e tenho a seguinte situação:

- Tenho a activity **Foo** com um botão que navega para a activity **Bar**.
- Em **Bar**, eu processo alguma informação e tenho um botão para voltar.
- Ao voltar, eu devo retornar essa informação processada para **Foo**

Gostaria de saber se já existe algum padrão implementado para fazer isso em Kotlin (Android) para que eu possa aprender já usando as melhores práticas...

> Nota: a princípio eu pensei em ter uma ViewModel implantada em **Foo** e tentar passar para **Bar** a instância da mesma, mas me pareceu um tanto quanto "forçado" por isso vim esclarecer melhor o "como fazer"

Comment: O jeito "canônico" seria usar Intents, pessoalmente prefiro usar SharedPreferences, a atividade B modifica um valor nas shared preferences da aplicação e a atividade A fica como listener de mudanças nas preferências. O uso de um singleton compartilhado entre as diversas atividades, talvez residindo numa classe estática, também é válido.

Comment: Eu diria que o titulo da pergunta não está muito claro, pois dá a ideia de herança entre as Activities, quando no exemplo `Foo` e `Bar` são distintas e não partilham de nenhuma relação de herança

Comment: Então creio que se eu pegar e usar uma VM que possa ser passada à segunda seja válida pois ela funcionaria como uma singleton correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a classe `Foo` deve, além de criar a intent, ter uma constante de referência para a chamada da função startActivityForResult:

```
val intent = Intent(this, Bar::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)

companion object{
    private const val REQUEST_CODE = 123
}
```

na classe `Bar`, você também vai precisar de uma variável de referência para a activity que chamou saber se o dado que está chegando é realmente o que você solicitou.

```
fun whenDataIsReady(){
   val intent = Intent()
   intent.putExtras("key", "value")
   setResult(RESULT_CODE, intent)
   finish()
}

companion object{
    const val RESULT_CODE = 111
}
```

De volta a `Foo`, na função onActivityResult você deve verificar se o `request code` foi o solicitado por `Foo` e se o `result code` foi o devolvido por `Bar`

```
fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int,resultCode: Int,data: Intent) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_CODE){
        //trate os dados que chegaram da intent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você deve usar OnActivityResult para pegar os dados:

Você inicia a Bar assim:

```
Intent(this,Bar::class.java);
        startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE);
```

Na classe Bar quando o butão voltar for pressionado:

```
 val intent = getIntent();
   intent.putExtra("chave", valor);
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();
```

E então recebe o valor na class Foo:

```
 fun onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      }
```